# What event will be triggered when a Window gets shown again from hidden state in WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight

```
var window = new Window();
window.Show(); //the Loaded Event will be triggered after this statement.
window.Hide();
window.Show();
```

Which Event will be triggered after the last statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window.Activated event is raised after every Show method

Comment: Everyone always talks about `ContentRendered` vs `Loaded`, but this was what I was looking for! Thanks!